# Split fixed width file into lines

Tags: awk, text-formatting

Have a fixed-length file where there is no newline separator between the lines, but every line is exactly 15 characters.

```
echo "John Doe       Jane Doe      Johny Doe      " > /tmp/every_line_is_15_characters.txt
```

is there any way to split it to:

```
John Doe
Jane Roe
Johny Doe
```

(obviously, there will be trailing whitespaces).

It can be done with java, python, etc, but what is the simplest way of splitting a file into fixed-width lines without using heavyweight programming languages? Perhaps awk or something?

Comment: Regarding `obviously, there will be trailing whitespaces` - there doesn't have to be, do you want there to be or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the `fold` command from GNU Coreutils:

```
$ fold -w15 /tmp/every_line_is_15_characters.txt
John Doe
Jane Doe      J
ohny Doe
```

(as you can see, your second field actually appears to have only 14 characters).

Failing that, you could use `sed` to insert a newline after every 15 characters:

```
sed 's/.\{15\}/&\n/g' /tmp/every_line_is_15_characters.txt
```

or perhaps `grep -o '.\{15\}'` to output non-overlapping matches of 15 arbitrary characters.

If you have GNU awk, you could use either `gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT=".{15}"; OFS="\n"} {$1=$1} 1'` or (if you know how many 15-character fields there are) `gawk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="15 15 15"; OFS="\n"} {$1=$1} 1'`. See for example [The GNU Awk User's Guide: 4.6.1 Processing Fixed-Width Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Fixed-width-data)

Comment: Thank you. 'fold' looks like the one. Couldn't find it with google's help.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT`, and `gensub()` with no trailing whitespace on each line:

```
$ awk -v RS='.{15}' 'RT{print gensub(/\s+$/,"",1,RT)}' file
John Doe
Jane Doe
Johny Doe
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -v RS='.{15}' -F'\\s+$' 'RT{$0=RT; print $1}' file
John Doe
Jane Doe
Johny Doe
```

The above was run on the output from `echo "John Doe       Jane Doe       Johny Doe      "`, i.e. after adjusting your 2nd field to be 15 rather than 14 characters.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6):**

```
$ raku -ne '.raku.put for .comb(15);' <<<'John Doe       Jane Doe       Johny Doe      '
"John Doe       "
"Jane Doe       "
"Johny Doe      "
```

Briefly, the `-ne` flags tell Raku to read input linewise, and the input is `comb`-ed to break it into 15 character chunks. The `raku` command is then used to double-quote and the output is printed linewise with `.put for`.

Add a call to `trim` to remove leading/trailing whitespace (conversely, drop the call to `raku` if no double-quotes are required):

```
$ raku -ne '.trim.raku.put for .comb(15);' <<<'John Doe       Jane Doe       Johny Doe      '
"John Doe"
"Jane Doe"
"Johny Doe"
```

Finally, even if you use Unicode you won't have any worries about proper spacing: with Raku you'll still cut your string into 15-character chunks (trimmed, below):

```
$ raku -ne '.trim.raku.put for .comb(15);' <<<'Иван Иванович  Джейн Доу      Василий Пупкин '
"Иван Иванович"
"Джейн Доу"
"Василий Пупкин"
```

*(Note: single-quoted 'here-string' notation `<<<` is used above to help in displaying the Raku code; `echo` or `cat` can be used just as easily).*

https://raku.org/